# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in For loop due to entry deleted from database. Help fix it

Tags: database, vb.net, for-loop, indexing

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TimeNow As DateTime
    TimeNow = DateTime.Now
    With ReservationTableDataGridView
        For i As Integer = 0 To (.Rows.Count - 1)
            ListView1.BackColor = Color.Black
            Dim ToBeTested As DateTime
            ToBeTested = (.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) #
            Console.WriteLine(ToBeTested)
            If ToBeTested > TimeNow.AddMinutes(45) Then
                Me.ReservationTableTableAdapter.Delete((.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value), (.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value), (.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value), (.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value))
                Me.ReservationTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerResDataBaseDataSet.ReservationTable)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to write some code to delete a reservation from a data base after it has been 45 minutes after the set reservation time has passed. I keep getting the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error. I believe this is because after it delete an item from the database it has less values then the index. Can anyone please help me to fix this?

This was the error gotten, {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"}. I believe this was due to the '#" line.

Comment: Try going backwards - `For i As Integer = (.Rows.Count - 1) to 0 Step -1` and see if you still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going backwards - `For i As Integer = (.Rows.Count - 1) to 0 Step -1`.

The issue is that you are deleting rows in the `ReservationTableDataGridView` as you try to iterate over them, thus changing the index.

By going backwards you always have a valid index.